# httpd (apache) 2.4 - .htaccess remove parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the URL parameter: `?filter_by`.

**From**

```
https://example.com/cat/actualites-cyclisme/santos-tour-down-under/?filter_by=popular7
```

**To**

```
https://example.com/cat/actualites-cyclisme/santos-tour-down-under
```

I tried this but unsuccessfully,  do not understand why...

```
RewriteRule /(.*)\?filter_by=^ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to remove a query parameter from any position in a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?filter_by=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: this might work better : `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,NE,L]` :)

Comment: That will work with just a single parameter but if there are more parameters then it won't